# moving from ant to maven project

Tags: java, maven, java-8, ant

I am planning to migrate from my existing ant project which is built on Java1.5  to maven project. How to proceed with this? Existing project has some deprecated jars used/ added in lib dir. I am not able to find those jars dependencies on maven central repository. Because of this I am not able to build the project.

Comment: You can import deprecated jars into your local maven repo, or to the team remote maven repo (if your team has one). And later, when you are able to build your project with maven, look for a way to replace them with modern alternatives.

Comment: Firstly create a new maven project.
Then migrate all your class in src/main/java, all your resources in src/main/resources and your tests in src/main/test.
In your pom, put all your dependencies (you can find mostly in apache website) that you have in your previous project.
Add some plugin and properties you need and it should be done...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project this will help